# Laptop screen turned mostly pink

Tags: linux, graphics-card

My Samsung laptop NP300E5A was just sitting on my desk when the screen suddenly turned to this: [image: laptop screen]

I hooked up a projector to the VGA port and everything looked fine on the projector - it's just messed up on my screen. I've also tried shutting down and letting everything cool before restarting to no avail. What is this called, and any thoughts on troubleshooting?

Comment: Try restarting linux. It looks like the top of the screen is ok and the bottom is not. A simple restart or turning your monitor on/off may fix it.

Comment: Could your laptop screen or the connecting cable have been damaged in any way? This looks like there may be some problem with the connection between your laptop screen and your graphics processor. Perhaps a wire or two has come slightly lose.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter that's possible. How can I access that wire?  I.e., what should I look for?

Comment: I had a look for details but it seems all Samsung make available on their site is the standard user-guide, rather than more in-depth technical manuals, which makes knowing how to get into the right part of the laptop tricky. I know it's a bit of a cop-out but I would probably suggest contacting Samsung directly to see if they can tell you how to access the internals. Once open it should just be a matter of checking any wires connecting to the LCD screen are fully in contact still, (these will either be wired into the motherboard, or connected via a detachable plastic connector).

Comment: Is the BIOS screen pink too? And it's only on the bottom 80% of the screen? If BIOS is ok, could be a software/driver problem, but I wouldn't expect that to happen in the middle of running, out of the blue. Maybe the screen is just failing, ribbon cable loose or breaking, etc...

Comment: @Xen2050 yea, it's messed up right at boot.

Comment: @bcf `Right at boot` is not the same thing as `in BIOS`. Pls get into your BIOS and check whether the BIOS screen displays the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this before on external monitors, but never on a laptop panel.  Basically your green color channel has become disconnected somehow.  With an external monitor connected via an analog VGA cable, you can reproduce this effect by pulling one side of the connector out slightly so it's crooked.

If the internal panel is connected with VGA, that would explain things, and it would be as simple as re-seating the connector to the motherboard.  However, I find it hard to believe that Samsung would've connected internally with VGA.  That leads me to believe that the green channel on the panel's DAC controller itself is not working.  If this is the case, then it's broken and there is nothing you can do except replace the panel.

Try re-seating the internal connector anyway and see if it fixes the problem.  Be very careful though.  Those internal ribbon connectors are known to be very fragile.

Comment: Looks like a real pain to get to the ends of that connector.  [Here's a few videos that show how to find the end that connects to the back of the LCD panel.](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=vid&q=NP300E5A+lcd)  Not sure how to find where it connects to the motherboard.